# working on sms sent through an application using node js

Tags: node.js, express, sms, twilio

I am working on sms using express frame work and i have installed 'twilio'

but the thing is sms is not getting sent and getting 304 error code 
This is what i have tried so far

```
   var _ = require('lodash');
var Sms = require('./sms.model');
var accountSid = '******************'; // Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/console
var authToken = '******************'; // Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console

var twilio = require('twilio');
var client = new twilio.RestClient(accountSid, authToken);
exports.sendSms = function(req, res) {
  console.log(accountSid);
  console.log(authToken);
      client.messages.create({
        body: 'Hello from Node',
        to: '*****', // Text this number
        from: '*****' // From a valid Twilio number
    }, function(err, message) {
        console.log(message.sid);
    });
};
```

and routing is done as below:

```
   var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./sms.controller');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', controller.index);
router.get('/sendSms', controller.sendSms);
router.get('/:id', controller.show);
router.post('/', controller.create);
router.put('/:id', controller.update);
router.patch('/:id', controller.update);
router.delete('/:id', controller.destroy);

module.exports = router;
```

Even the console messages are not getting printed.
I dont understand the issue 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see where you are calling the `sendSms()` function. May be you can provide that piece of code.

Comment: @Yeiniel Updated my question

Comment: I still don't see where you are using the `sendSms()` function. If the first file is the one you are requiring on the second as `./sms.controller` then you need to route requests to the `controller.sendSms` somewhere. Could you add information about the url and method you are using to call the function?

Comment: Do you get the 304 error code from your application? Do the other routes work? I just tested the Twilio part of your code, and that route seems to work fine. I think you'll need to check where in your code the routes don't work

Comment: @MarcosPlacona, Actually i did a mistake in route file which i had fixed and the second thing is i gave wrong phone number which doesnot allowed me to send messages and the problem with twilio is i need to verify all the phone numbers to whom i am sending messages is their any other solution where i could send messages without this verification process?

Comment: You can send messages to numbers without verifying them in Twilio by upgrading your account with some credit. Then you can send to any number that can receive an SMS.